# What will power a Smeltery?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I am playing the Journey to the Core modpack on the ATLauncher.

I have a functional smeltery from TK, but no lava to power it. I know the a YouTuber used molten pyrotheum, but I haven't found any of that. I have searched multiple wikis, and they all only mention lava.

**How can Tinkers' Contruct furnaces be powered, in To the Core?**

Comment: @ALX actually, we do. We do not, however, provide support for modded crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't played Journey to the Core, but the things that power a TiCon smeltery are Lava and [Blazing Pyrotheum from Thermal Foundation](http://teamcofh.com/docs/thermal-foundation/fluids/blazing-pyrotheum/).  Your best bet is to find some lava if possible, either in a surface lake, near bedrock, or the nether.  The modpack author [says in a post about the pack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/mod-packs/2323043-journey-to-the-core-modpack?comment=11) that lava is found generally around below level 30, but occasionally higher.  Dig down and use your map to find some.

If you want to use pyrotheum, you'll have to craft it from components.  It's a much later-game fuel, though, providing much faster melting in return for higher cost.  By default, you create Blazing Pyrotheum by putting Pyrotheum Dust in a magma crucible.  Pyrotheum Dust is crafted with one each of pulverized coal, sulfur, redstone, and blaze powder.  However, these recipes might be changed by the modpack.